# Animating an Element so it changes from display:none with CSS

Tags: css, animation, display, transition

I have a menu system where that when a ‘menu’ button is clicked some simple javascript allows a mobile menu to be shown as a drop-down.

I would like to have it so this menu transitions / animates in, but the display: none property seems to not be animatable with CSS animations.  I don’t really want to just use opacity: 0 because the mobile menu will then be in the document flow, and on desktop devices I don’t wish this to be the case.

Is there any CSS solution to this?  When I use the Greensock animation library, it allows you to animate or change the ‘display’ property. I can’t seem to get this to work with CSS animations though?

I’ve created a simple pen where I’ve just used a single div that animates (to keep it simple I haven't included any JS click events etc with this).

As you can see I’ve commented out the display: none on both the CSS for the id#bluebox and on the @keyframes animation.  If you un-comment these you can see the problem that is created.

https://codepen.io/emilychews/pen/xPWddZ

CSS

```
#bluebox {
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: blue;
  animation: appear 1s ease-in forwards;
  opacity: 0;
/*   display: none; */
}

@keyframes appear {
  0% {/*display: none;*/ opacity: 0}
  1% {display: block; opacity: 0.1;}
  100% {opacity: 1;}
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="bluebox"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by adding a transform: scaleY(0) to the element, and then animated this with the element on opacity: 0 for the first 1% of the animation, so you couldn't see the element 'scale up' so to speak. I used scale instead of width and height because width and height properties don't animate very well in terms of achieving the 60fps smoothness.

CSS

```
#bluebox {
margin-left: 0px;
margin-top: 0px;
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
background: blue;
animation: appear 1s ease-in forwards;
opacity: 0;
transform: scaleY(0);
}   

@keyframes appear {
  0% {opacity: 0;}
  1% {opacity: 0; transform: scaleY(1)}
  100% {opacity: 1; transform: scaleY(1)}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case, since you're attempting to animate the element, I would say you should probably use width and height to your advantage instead.

Something like this could act as a substitute for display none. ([Codepen](https://codepen.io/ChaseIngebritson/pen/ooqeGK))

```
#bluebox {
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
}

@keyframes appear {
  0% {
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
  }
  100% {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
  }
}
```

The width or height could also be replaced with your end width/height to allow for a more natural animation, depending on your goal. I can update the Codepen to include an example of what I mean if you'd like.

Let me know if this is what you were aiming for!

Edit: Fixed the Codepen link